# Is it possible to have Heroku Local run like nodemon?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm new to Heroku, a little bit less to NodeJS (and Nodemon).

I am now using `heroku local` to run my app in local (and be as close as possible to my prod environment) but I'd like to have my app rebuilt and restarted everytime I make a change in local (as with Nodemon for example).

Is there nay way to do this with `heroku local`?

Thanks!
Nicolas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart Heroku local on file change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146236/restart-heroku-local-on-file-change)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but came up while I was searching for the same. There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561121

This is what I have in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --exec 'heroku local' --signal SIGTERM"
}
```

Comment: I actually had found an answer and forgot to post it here. But I'm using this in my `Procfile`: `web: nodemon server.js`

Comment: This causes an infinite loop, bc heroku local calls npm start.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody coming across this post in search of a solution. As mentioned by **nicolasdaudin** in response to **tom**, you can add nodemon to the heroku Procfile (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

`web: nodemon index.js`

Note that nodemon must be installed globally for this to work:

`npm i -g nodemon`

Then you should be able to run heroku locally as normal with nodemon watching for changes:

`heroku local web`